# Angular2: proper way to upgrading

Tags: angular, package, upgrade

so, it's time to upgarde from rc4 to rc5 for me, but would like to know the proper steps...

the easiest way would be just to change the version numbers in my package file... but not sure if that would be correct? plus where can I find the current version numbers for the router and forms? right now my package.json files refarding angular looks like this:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to take a look at Angular 2 doc, specifically: [RC4 to RC5](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html)

For the dependencies the [Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) is the way to go if you want to adapt yours.

I too am Refactoring my code, good luck ^^